# Linux - FirewallD - Why is ping blocked?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, ping, firewalld

I know that the `drop` zone (my default zone) in FirewallD blocks all incoming traffic, including icmp, so also ping.
The `FedoraWorkstation` zone, does not block icmp.

But where can I see this? If apply a `--list-all` to both zones, nothing differs in terms of icmp.

```
drop (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlp2s0
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 



FedoraWorkstation
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two is the assigned **TARGET**.

According to firewalld man page:

target="ACCEPT|%%REJECT%%|DROP"
           Can be used to accept, reject or drop every packet. The ACCEPT
           target is used in the trusted zone, every packet will be accepted.
           The %%REJECT%% target is used in the block zone, every packet will
           be rejected with the default firewalld reject type. The DROP target
           is used in the drop zone, every packet will be dropped. The default
           target is {chain}*ZONE*{zone} and will be used if the target is not
           specified. If other than the default target is used, all settings
           except interface and source are ignored, because the first rule
           created in firewall for this zone is 'jump to target'.

Now, if you set FedoraWorkstation target to either DROP or %%REJECT%% you will be able to drop/reject packets.